# jQuery Slider Orbit - moving bullets

Tags: jquery, orbit

I'm using the excellent Zurb plugin [Orbit](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin) on my homepage, and I'm trying to move the bullets (typically below the slider) to a different location on the page (in this case, in the header above the slider)

I tried the following code:

```
jQuery('.orbit-header').append(jQuery('ul.orbit-bullets'));
```

This removes the bullets, but they don't appear. I don't think it's that they haven't been generated yet, as I tried putting this in a function on the slide change and that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add your html or make an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tallphil/mZYX9/4/

Comment: they appear down of the page can you explain more your question ?

Comment: I want to move the bullets so that they're inline with the header, eg: "Latest Projects •••"

If I uncomment the javascript line to move them, they disappear but don't appear in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you need to modify the css :

http://jsfiddle.net/Awea/mZYX9/10/

Comment: I'm not so keen on this approach as it's not very flexible - for example, if I change the text in the heading it will cause problems. But yes - this does work. Thanks @Awea!

Comment: Another way was to edit the js to insert bullets where you want to make a float left for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.orbit-bullets {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    top: -16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - your suggestion seems to work in the JSFiddle. Sadly this question was over two years ago and already answered, the site was finished and has even been recently redesigned in that time ;)

Comment: I hadn't invented my time machine till a week ago, so I'm doing the best I can here with limited time space continuum options.  Consolation up vote for the nice thought?